# Fluent Assertion: Dictionary Should BeEquivalentTo Excluding Property on Dictionary Value

Tags: c#, linq, nunit, fluent-assertions

I have a class called HandRank which has an Id property. The Id property is generated by my database.

```cs
public class HandRank
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int Rank { get; set; }
}
```

I have a method called GetHandRanks which returns a `Dictionary<string, HandRank>`.

In my tests, I am seeding an in memory database. As the Id property is determined by the database, I wish to exclude it from my assertion.

Below is my test but it fails because The Id property is not set in the expectedResult. I am not setting the Id because I do not know what the Id will be when generated by the database.

```cs
[Test]
public void Test()
{
    // arrange
    var expectedResult = new Dictionary<string, HandRank>
    {
        { "aaa", new HandRank { Rank = 1} },
        { "bbb", new HandRank { Rank = 2} }
    };

    // act
    var actualResult = _handRankManager.GetHandRanks();

    // Assert
    actualResult.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expectedResult);
}
```

I expect that the assertion will need to be something like the below but I cannot get the lambda in the Excluding method correct.

```cs
actualResult.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expectedResult, options => options.Excluding(x => x.Values.Id));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, if you *only* want to filter out `HandRank.Id`, then you could use the following:

```
actualResult.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expectedResult, opt =>
    opt.Excluding(m => 
        m.SelectedMemberInfo.DeclaringType == typeof(HandRank) 
        && m.SelectedMemberInfo.Name.Equals(nameof(HandRank.Id))
    ));
```

If ignoring properties named `"Id"` is something you want to use in many parts of your test, you're better off taking it out into a function like this:

```
public static EquivalencyAssertionOptions<_> ExcludeId<_>(EquivalencyAssertionOptions<_> opt)
    => opt.Excluding(m => m.SelectedMemberInfo.Name.Equals("Id"));
```

And use it as so:

```
actual.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expected, ExcludeId);
```

Should work against Dictionaries, Lists, objects with deep properties, anything you can think of. It will blanket ignore all members named `Id`.

---

**Edit 2022:**

As per feedback below, 6.0 had a [breaking change](https://github.com/fluentassertions/fluentassertions/pull/1379) that flattened `SelectedMemberInfo` properties into `IMemberInfo`, which makes the exclusion nicer to read.

```
actual.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expected, opt =>
  opt.Excluding(member => 
    member.DeclaringType == typeof(X) 
    && member.Name.Equals(nameof(X.Id))
  ));
```

Comment: Notes: 
You will need `using FluentAssertions.Equivalency;`
As of version 6, you don't need `SelectedMemberInfo` anymore. Source: https://fluentassertions.com/releases/

Answer (score 2):

I tried the answers mentioned in this question(none of them worked for me), but for me, the way of excluding work successfully is below.

```
actual.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expected, opt =>
                opt.For(m => m.Values).Exclude(x => x.Id));
```

This is with version 6.7.0